# No actualiza ID especifico

Tags: php, html

tengo el siguiente código en teoría lo que hace es actualizar el valor de estatus si esta definido y si no lo asigna como "ENVIADO", el problema es que solo cambia el estatus del primer valor así seleccione 5 cambia únicamente el primer valor, el restante los asigna como si no estuviera definidos.

Para definir o no una variable utilizo un check que al dar clic se asinga el valor como "RECIBIDO" y si no no se define.

```
  $CODIGO= array();
  $UNITARIO= array();
  $CANTIDAD= array();
  $ESTATUS= array();
  $CONTEO= array();
  foreach($_POST['cod_pro'] as $key=>$value)
      $CODIGO[]= $value;
  foreach($_POST['unitario'] as $key=>$value)
      $UNITARIO[]= $value;            
  foreach($_POST['cantidad'] as $key=>$value)
      $CANTIDAD[]= $value;
  foreach($_POST['estatus'] as $key=>$value)  
      $ESTATUS[]= $value;     
  foreach($_POST['conteo'] as $key=>$value)
      $CONTEO[]= $value;  
              for($i=0; $i<count($CODIGO); $i++)
              {
                          
//valida si esta definida la variable ESTATUS si no lo esta le asigna valor "ENVIADO"       
  if(isset($ESTATUS[$i])) {
      }else{      
      $ESTATUS[$i]="ENVIADO";
      }   
              echo"ID:$CODIGO[$i] - $ESTATUS[$i] <p>";    
                  IF($ESTATUS[$i]=="RECIBIDO" AND $CONTEO[$i]==$CANTIDAD[$i] OR $CONTEO[$i]==NULL){
                      //ACTUALIZAR MISMO CONTEO
                      $_UPDATE_SQL="UPDATE $CD_DEVOL SET ESTATUS='$ESTATUS[$i]',REC_FECHA='$HORA_FECHA_ACTUAL-$NOMBRE_USUARIO_COMPLETO' WHERE ODD='$ODD' AND CODIGO='$CODIGO[$i]'"; 
                      if (mysqli_query($conexion_CD,$_UPDATE_SQL)) {
                      } else {echo "Error: " . $_UPDATE_SQL . "" . mysqli_error($conexion_CD);}
                  }ELSEIF($ESTATUS[$i]=="RECIBIDO" AND $CONTEO[$i]!=$CANTIDAD[$i]){
                      $SUBTOTAL[$i]=$UNITARIO[$i]*$CONTEO[$i];
                      //ACTUALIZAR CONTEO DIFERENTE
                      $_UPDATE_SQL="UPDATE $CD_DEVOL SET CANTIDAD='$CONTEO[$i]', SUBTOTAL='$SUBTOTAL[$i]', ESTATUS='$ESTATUS[$i]',REC_FECHA='$HORA_FECHA_ACTUAL-$NOMBRE_USUARIO_COMPLETO' WHERE ODD='$ODD' AND CODIGO='$CODIGO[$i]'";
                      if (mysqli_query($conexion_CD,$_UPDATE_SQL)) {
                      } else {echo "Error: " . $_UPDATE_SQL . "" . mysqli_error($conexion_CD);}
                  }ELSEIF($ESTATUS[$i]=="DEVUELTO"){
                      //ACTUALIZAR DEVUELTO
                      $_UPDATE_SQL="UPDATE $CD_DEVOL SET ESTATUS='$ESTATUS[$i]' WHERE ODD='$ODD' AND CODIGO='$CODIGO[$i]'"; 
                      if (mysqli_query($conexion_CD,$_UPDATE_SQL)) {
                      } else {echo "Error: " . $_UPDATE_SQL . "" . mysqli_error($conexion_CD);}
                  }ELSE{
                      //ACTUALIZAR DEVUELTO
                      $_UPDATE_SQL="UPDATE $CD_DEVOL SET ESTATUS='$ESTATUS[$i]' WHERE ODD='$ODD' AND CODIGO='$CODIGO[$i]'"; 
                      if (mysqli_query($conexion_CD,$_UPDATE_SQL)) {
                      } else {echo "Error: " . $_UPDATE_SQL . "" . mysqli_error($conexion_CD);}
                  }   
              }
```

Comment: Puedes poner un ejemplo de que estas añadiendo en los arrays y que usas para hacer esa actualización? Me da la sensación de que estas trabajando con objetos, pero por tu código parece no ser así. Lo cierto es que me es algo complicado entender lo que pides ya que no concuerda el enunciado con el código o eso creo.

Comment: Claro, este es un fragmento del formulario. `<input class="estatus" type="checkbox" value="RECIBIDO" name="estatus[]"/>`

Comment: Sigo sin entender que hay dentro del array $ESTATUS y que relación tiene este con el resto de arrays. Acaso estas metiendo valores en el array sin ningún tipo de identificador y sabes a que corresponden por el orden? Intenta modificar la pregunta y déjanos un ejemplo amplio y claro con el que podamos precisar con exactitud que sucede

Comment: Intentando buscar la causa del problema que expones, lo primero que se aprecia es un código algo desorganizado. Por ejemplo, ¿por qué usas tantos `foreach` dentro de otros `foreach` y además un `for`  dentro de ellos, llenando además otros arrays dentro de esos `foreach` que además usas para deplegar el `for`? ¿Parece un trabalengua lo que te pregunto? Pues así es como está armado tu código. Piensa en simplificar las cosas... quizá el problema principal aquí es la lógica que estás usando, es demasiado rocambolesca.